# android map doesn't appear

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

i'm trying to make a sample map application, but the map doesn't appear on screen. I'm following this tutorial http://www.tutos-android.com/position-utilisateur-google-map-android and i'm using the Key for browser apps (with referers) .When i followed this tutorial http://blog.rolandl.fr/1230-android-la-geolocalisation-et-lapi-google-maps-android-v2  with the same key it worked but it gave me wrong position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first tutorial there is no mention about Google Maps API V2 key which you need for using Google Maps in Android. Also the first tutorial is for Google Maps API V1 which is deprecated.

The second tutorial is definitly what you need. If you had wrong position its maybe because GPS was not used. Check if GPS was turned on and you have these lines in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network"/>
<permission
        android:name="cz.nuc.wheelgo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>  <!-- replace name of the package by yours -->
<uses-permission android:name="cz.nuc.wheelgo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-feature
  android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  android:required="true"/>
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzgkugSgsghsei2256Y7XN6xSGj-o"/>  <!-- your key -->
```

To enable your location on the map use:

```
GoogleMap mMap;
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

I suggest you to take a look on sample in Android-sdk in path: `android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps\`